# JNA How to wrap interface written in C++

Tags: java, c++, parsing, wrapper

I already know how to wrap an Structure , but I need some help with interfaces.
The interface I want to wrap is the [IImageList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commoncontrols/nn-commoncontrols-iimagelist).

But I have now clue how to create an java class out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, but you will need access to the header file.  The [IImageList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commoncontrols/nn-commoncontrols-iimagelist) documentation tells you this comes from [commoncontrols.h](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.16299.0/um/commoncontrols.h).  Refer to this source file for the following discussion.

Although not mandatory, for organization you will want to create a Java class for the header file, e.g., `CommonControls.java`.  Inside that create a class for the interface, extending JNA's [`Unknown`](https://static.javadoc.io/net.java.dev.jna/jna/4.5.2/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/COM/Unknown.html) class and add the method(s) you want. The methods should use [`_invokeNativeObject()`](https://static.javadoc.io/net.java.dev.jna/jna/4.5.2/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/COM/COMInvoker.html#Z:Z_invokeNativeObject-int-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Class-) (or the `void` or `int` variants).  The key point here is that you'll need the `vtableId`.  This is where you go back to the header file listed earlier.  Find the `IImageListVtbl` entry in the header (it's on line 322) and count the methods (0-indexed) to find which ID corresponds to the method you want.  vtableID = 0 would be `QueryInterface`.  Id 1 is `AddRef`.  And so on.

See, as an example, how I implemented several interfaces from wbemcli.h in [this Wbemcli.java class](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/master/oshi-core/src/main/java/oshi/jna/platform/windows/Wbemcli.java).  One example implements the [`IEnumWbemClassObject::Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wbemcli/nf-wbemcli-ienumwbemclassobject-next) method thus:

```
class IEnumWbemClassObject extends Unknown {

    public IEnumWbemClassObject(Pointer pvInstance) {
        super(pvInstance);
    }

    public HRESULT Next(int lTimeOut, int uCount, PointerByReference ppObjects, IntByReference puReturned) {
        // Next is 5th method of IEnumWbemClassObjectVtbl in
        // WbemCli.h
        return (HRESULT) _invokeNativeObject(4,
                new Object[] { getPointer(), lTimeOut, uCount, ppObjects, puReturned }, HRESULT.class);
    }
}
```

You can add multiple methods (or all of them) in the same class.

Comment: There was something I did wrong but now a Invalid memory access Expection is thrown when i run the method

Comment: @MrMarnic Can you explain for me how you fixed it? I try to use the ShGetImageList function with this IImagelist as a parameter but it also gives me an invalid memory access exception

Comment: I don’t remember how I did it but here is the source the library that I made that does exactly that : https://github.com/MrMarnic/JIconExtract

Answer (score -2):

This ended up being the solution:

```
class IImageList extends Unknown {
    public IImageList(Pointer pvInstance) {
        super(pvInstance);
    }

    public WinNT.HRESULT GetIcon(int i, int flags, PointerByReference picon) {
        return (WinNT.HRESULT) _invokeNativeObject(10,
                new Object[]{this.getPointer(), i, flags, picon},WinNT.HRESULT.class);
    }
}
```

---

Solution pulled from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51968763/3002139); written by [mrmarnic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10260109/mrmarnic).